# mesa vulkan dinner not updating ubuntu 20.04

Tags: updates, 20.04, vulkan

My computer updates on a daily basis, but I've noticed over the last 5-7 days since upgrading to 20.04 the Mesa VULKAN driver (3.7mb) does not hold after install. Every time I reboot the computer and click software update it always returns! 
I don't know why it does this. Can anyone help?

I've checked all the PPAs, run sudo get-update and sudo get-upgrade and there are no error messages returning or anything to update further.. Or repair
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How did you install it? And why you are using capslock?

Comment: When Software Update automatically appears on boot up it always shows as needing downloaded and installed. Apologies with the caps lock lol

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo apt-get install mesa-vulkan-drivers` ?

Comment: Terminal advise it is already the newest version (20.2~git2005060730.870b6a~oibaf~f).

Comment: Until I reboot the computer again...???

Answer (score 0):

This morning in boot up software update showed a fix for my software update app. It downloaded and installed. Mesa VULKAN driver is no longer required. Problem solved